# How to completely shut MySQL server down on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I had mysql server running. I stopped it, and removed it (apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client)

I then manually removed the directories:

```
/var/lib/mysql
/var/run/mysqld
```

I rebooted. But when I type mysql, I get the following message:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I get the same error message when I type `service mysql stop`

This means mysql server is still running. How do I get rid of it completely and stop the process. My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Comment: Sounds like the process isn't running based on the can't connect message

Comment: What makes you think that the error indicates that MySQL server is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql-server `mysql-client` are simply [MetaPackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) that link to packages like `mysql-server-5.5` m`ysql-client-5.5`.

If you uninstalled the meta packages, and not the version specific packages, then mysql is still installed.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with `dpkg -l` that you don't have any mysql packages installed on the server. There seems to be some MySQL utility left that tries to connect to your server. Remove all the mysql packages with `apt-get` and you should be able to boot cleanly.